# Какой тип должно иметь поле MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Имеется задание вывести кол - во студенитов, которые имеют серию паспорта 0301. С MySQL знакомство начал сравнительно недавно. Какой тип лучше присвоить серии паспорта? Ведь она состоит из двух букв и шести цифр, значит INT вроде как не подходит. А разбивать серию на два поля типа серия (бувами) и серия (цифры) - несообразно. Или лучше создать VARCHAR(8), а потом воспользоваться какой то функцией, которая считаетвсе символі и, если 3,4,5,6 соответствуют 0301 - то студент подходит? Есть ли такая?

Comment: Лично у меня серия - 4 цифры. А на Украине серия - две буквы, а цифры это номер

Comment: зависит от стран на которые ориентирован проект. разные страны, разный формат номера

Comment: Все правильно,спасибо

Comment: @Alex,  и Вам тоже

Comment: @MuscledBoy уточните пожалуйста, вопрос закрыт?

Comment: @Alex, я так понимаю, раз задание из российского источника, то и ориентировано на стандарт России. Но, если Вас не затруднит, как бы ВЫ организовали данный момент для стандарта Украины?

Comment: @MuscledBoy для паспортов украины лучше всего использовать CHAR(2) для серии и MEDIUMINT для номера(или INT)

Comment: @Alex, спасибо за консультацию

Comment: @MuscledBoy в вопросе стоит серия `0301`, поэтому int для серии не подходит - либо char или varchar, т.к. ведущий ноль не будет записан.

Comment: Вообще в идеале нужен один varchar и побольше, и к нему еще поле "вид документа удостоверяющего личность". А иначе у вас не смогут обучатся иностранные студенты. И возможно какие то справочники у каких видов документа что допустимо, что бы не позволять вводить некорректные данные. И заодно там же к типу документа смещение номера, для Украины там будет 2, для России 4. Так что если это в качестве обучения - то 2 поля, если реальный проект подумайте какие документы на самом деле могут быть у студентов ...

Comment: @Alex, точно, а я ведь об єтом моменте и не подумал. Спасибо

Comment: @Mike, благодарю за полный ответ. Буд разбираться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В идеале выглядит так:

Наименование данных ->      Тип данных  ->    Примечание

Серия паспорта      ->      Строка      -> Серия и номер паспорта обязательны для идентификации

Номер паспорта      ->      Число       ->

Comment: спасибо, Вас понял